# What happens if you are pulled over for speeding but not given a ticket?

Tags: traffic, driving, speeding

This is probably a duplicate question, but I'm very freaked out about what happened. I apologize if it is.

I'm a teenager who just got pulled over for the first time (unbeknownst to be, the on-ramp for a local interstate had a speed limit of 45, not 65 as I thought. I was going 71). The cop put on his lights and I pulled over. I gave him my license and he took it to his car and gave it back to me. He then went back to his car and let me go. He didn't give me any papers or anything, but I'm really scared. Did I get a ticket?

Comment: What jurisdiction?  Normally, if the police let you go without handing you an actual physical paper ticket, printed with the legal text of a citation for a moving violation, you have not in fact been given a ticket.  Try image search for some examples.

Comment: What state?  In every state I'm familiar with you are required to sign and receive a copy of a citation for a moving violation.

Comment: I'm not aware of any state that actually has speed limits on ramps.  The few times I've seen them, they are yellow, which means advisory only.  Which is probably why he let you go, although he could use the very vague "speed unsafe for conditions."

Comment: @Andy, I'm aware of one ramp with a speed limit, but it's a combination bridge/on-ramp that extends for nearly a mile, and I've never seen the police enforce the speed limit past the split between the east-bound and west-bound parts of the ramp.

Answer (score 3):

In CA, with no papers given to you, there is no ticket. You are required to sign the ticket, which you obviously did not do.